# How can I embed a salesforce report(not a chart) in a lightning page?

Tags: reporting

I want to show a salesforce report on a lightning page.

I have tried to embed a report in a lightning component by using 
iframe tag but
it automatically opens another page. 
Is there any way to show it within the page?

I have found this article on showing a report on a visualforce page but cannot find an equivalent way for a lightning page/ lightning component.
https://mode.com/help/articles/embed-in-salesforce/

Comment: By lightning page, do you mean VisualForce? By lightning component do you mean aura component, visualforce component or LWC?

Comment: I am sorry that my question was not clear. I mean aura component by lightning component. And I think an application page is what it's called when I mentioned to "a lightning page". (i don't mean VF page by it.)